# Pi HAT Waveform Generator for Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: pi-3b+, hat

I am looking for a Pi HAT capable of generating 300 kHz sine waves at about 8 samples per waveform with my Raspberry Pi 3B+. Sampling rate required is around 2.5 MSps. Output voltage ideally needs to be at least 3.3V or higher.

In the past, I have used a DAC HAT made by this man from diymat.co.uk but unfortunately I think he is no longer making them anymore.

Struggling to find a replacement HAT to cope with the application and would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Pi HAT Waveform Generator for Raspberry Pi 3B+
> 2. 300 kHz sine waves at about 8 samples per waveform
> 3. Sampling rate required is around 2.5 MSps.

Have you considered the function generator modules?  They are as small as 2.5cm x 5cm, so can piggybacked on to Rpi.

***References***

[AliExpress AD9850 DDS Signal Generator Module 0-40MHz 2 Sine Wave and 2 Square Low-pass Filter Crystal Oscillator Test Equipment Board US $12.45](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/AD9850-DDS-Signal-Generator-Module-0-40MHz-2-Sine-Wave-and-2-Square-Low-pass-Filter/32847153218.html?spm=a2g0w.10010108.1000016.1.67205496N5RmST&isOrigTitle=true)

[AliExpress ICL8038 Sig Gen Med/Low Freq 10Hz-450KHz Triangular/Rectangular/Sine Wave Generator Module 12V to 15V US$2.59](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/ICL8038-Signal-G-n-rateur-Moyen-Faible-Fr-quence-10-hz-450-khz-Triangulaire-Rectangulaire-Onde/32884149123.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.33.9eed274eVDOtIR&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_0_10084_10083_10887_10307_321_453_322_454_10618_536_10065_317_537_10068_319_10059_10103_10884_10696%2Csearchweb201603_0%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=4ca8efc3-5304-4dfb-87d9-24f7b2e71173&algo_expid=4ca8efc3-5304-4dfb-87d9-24f7b2e71173-4)

[AD9850 CMOS, 125 MHz Complete DDS Synthesizer Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9850.pdf)

[ICL8038 Precision Waveform Generator/Voltage Controlled Oscillator September 1998 File Number 2864.3](http://www.mit.edu/~6.331/icl8038data.pdf)

[Everything You Always Wanted to Know About the ICL8038 Application Note November 199 AN013.1 Author: Bill O’Neil](http://www.mit.edu/~6.331/icl8038info.pdf)

AliExpress AD9850 DDS Signal Generator Module Features

```
1. AD9850: 0-40MHz.
2. 2 sine wave and 2 square wave output.
3. After the 20-30MHz frequency harmonics increases, the waveform will be less and less clean.
4. Square Wave: 0-1MHz.
5. Low-pass filter with 70MHz, so the waveform better than SN.
6. Parallel and serial data input can be selected via a jumper.
7. DA produced the benchmark pin (PIN12) leads for easy adjustment to do the magnitude of the output waveform Application.
8. Comparator reference input voltage generated by the variable resistor, the resistor can be adjusted duty cycle square wave of different.
9. Active AD9850 125MHz crystal oscillator modules.
10. Dimension:4.5cm x 2.6cm
```

[image: 8038 sig gen]

Comment: Thank you those are good suggestions! Sorry I forgot to add in the original post that the output voltage from the signal I was looking for needs to be around 3.3V (or higher). These function generator modules seem to only output at 1V or so. The reason I need it at 3.3V is because I already have amplifiers made to take that 3.3V up to the required voltage

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I remember I needed to supply 12V to the 8038 sig gen module and got around 2V sine output.  The max Vcc is 15V, which means at most 3V output only.